# CSS style not applying on ionic app file opened inside an iframe

Tags: css, iframe, ionic-framework

I'm trying to open an ionic v1 app ion model view file inside an iframe inside an $ionicPopup. It works fine except that the iframe content shows as plain html and ionic CSS styling is not applying.

ion model view file card.html:

```
<ion-modal-view id="pageid" class="pane" cache-view="false">
   <ion-header-bar class="bar-light">
    <h1 class="title"><center>Welcome</center></h1>
    <div class="buttons" >

    </div>
  </ion-header-bar> 
  <ion-content scroll="true">

<ion-card>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-start>
      <img src="img/marty-avatar.png">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>Marty McFly</h2>
    <p>November 5, 1955</p>
  </ion-item>

  <img src="img/advance-card-bttf.png">

  <ion-card-content>
    <p>Wait a minute. Wait a minute, Doc. Uhhh... Are you telling me that you built a time machine... out of a DeLorean?! Whoa. This is heavy.</p>
  </ion-card-content>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button icon-left clear small>
        <ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
        <div>12 Likes</div>
      </button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button icon-left clear small>
        <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
        <div>4 Comments</div>
      </button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col center text-center>
      <ion-note>
        11h ago
      </ion-note>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

</ion-card>

  </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

$ionicPopup code where the card.html is opened inside an iframe:

```
var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
template: '<iframe style="margin-top:0% !important; padding-top:0% !important; " id="iframeid" src="templates/card.html" scrolling="yes" width="100%" height="200" allowscriptaccess="always" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    title: 'Card Information',
    scope: $scope,
    buttons: [
      { text: 'Cancel',
        type: 'button-energized', onTap: function(e) { $scope.userCancel=true; } },
      {
        text: '<b>OK</b>',
        type: 'button-positive',
        onTap: function(e) {

            return $scope.data.Msg;

        }
      }
    ]
  });
```

Any solutions?

Comment: you have to post your code, this way no one will attend to help you

Comment: your styles rules from "parent" page will not apply to the page that comes from Iframe, it's simply impossible. You will need to serve separate css file "integrated" to iFrame content's head part

Comment: Ok, How to integrate "separate css file to iFrame content's head part " ?

Comment: In other words, is it possible to integrate these     <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">  into card.html

Comment: Why do you need to include an iframe?

Comment: I want to make a scrollable  content inside a fixed size popup